# Symlink link inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to automate the following. I mount an on-host volume. Inside this one, there are two subfolders A and B. Inside my Docker container, I create a symlink link inside A toward B. Here is what I get:

```
A
└─ C -> B
B
```

So it works perfectly.

Now, I want this symlink link to be created automatically after the folder is mounted on the host. Is that possible in Docker?

Comment: Is the folder mount an on-host volume, or a container volume?

Comment: You should be able to do this in an entrypoint script that runs at container startup; have you tried similar approaches?

Comment: Or if the directory `A` is part of the image, `ln -s` will happily create a "broken" link that points at a non-existent destination, to be created later.

Comment: @halfer host-volume

Comment: @DavidMaze I wanted to avoid any script :/

Comment: You don't need a script for this - make the creation of a broken symlink part of your image build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned David Maze
Because the directory A is part of the image, `ln -s` will happily create a "broken" link that points at a non-existent destination, to be created later.